# How to fetch the requested graphQL query attributes in resolver function with Ariadne

Tags: python, flask, graphql, apollo, ariadne-graphql

I have created a Flask server in Python and used Ariadne to bind Python functions to Apollo GraphQL schema. I have followed this guide - [Apollo GraphQL with Python](https://www.apollographql.com/blog/graphql/python/complete-api-guide/)

It's working as expected but I want to query only those fields in my underlying data source which the client requests from the GraphQL query. So, I need to access the requested query in the resolver function, which I am unable to figure out how.

This is my Flask /graphQL API:

```
import json

from api import app
from ariadne.constants import PLAYGROUND_HTML
from flask import request, jsonify
from ariadne import load_schema_from_path, make_executable_schema, snake_case_fallback_resolvers, graphql_sync, ObjectType
from queries import get_asset_resolver

query = ObjectType("Query")
query.set_field("getAsset", get_asset_resolver)

type_defs = load_schema_from_path("./schema.graphql")
schema = make_executable_schema(type_defs, query, snake_case_fallback_resolvers)


@app.route("/graphql", methods=["GET"])
def graphql_playground():
    return PLAYGROUND_HTML, 200


@app.route("/graphql", methods=["POST"])
def graphql_server():
    data = request.get_json()
    print('GraphQL request: ', data)
    success, result = graphql_sync(
        schema,
        data,
        context_value=request,
        debug=app.debug
    )
    print('Result from resolver: ', success, result)
    status_code = 200 if success else 400
    return jsonify(result), status_code
```

And this is my resolver function:

```
from ariadne import convert_kwargs_to_snake_case

import sqlquerybuilder
import runquery


@convert_kwargs_to_snake_case
def get_asset_resolver(obj, info, filters):

    # I want to fetch the requested query attributes here

    query = sqlquerybuilder.build_query_for_assets(filters)
    assets = runquery.run_query_for_assets(query)
    return assets
```